# Connect to Synology database with python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mariadb, synology

I don't have experience in databases, and I want to connect to a MariaDB10 database in a Synology NAS using python. I'm completely lost.

So far I tried the following code:

```
import mysql.connector as msq
connection=msq.connect(host="192.168.0.36",
                       port="3307",
                       unix_socket="run/mysqld/mysqld10.sock",
                       user="user", 
                       password='pwd',
```

I get an output like this:

```
DatabaseError: Host '192.168.0.18' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server
```

I also don't understand why the ip changes. Probably there are many things wrong on that code. Can someone please help me? did you do it before?

Comment: the user need to have access to connnect from host/ip 192.168.0.18.. Check the `mysql.user` table.. The user's host access explained in the manual [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/account-names.html) and [there](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-user.html)

Comment: Firewall?  `GRANTs`?

Answer (score 0):

It works! Thanks Raymond, I had to create a user for my database within phpmyadmin.